# Remoção de caracteres especiais no Software R

Tags: r

no banco de dados abaixo na coluna 7 (Titulo da coluna é Rodada) está escrito "1ª Rodada". Como remover o "ª" e manter somente "1 Rodada"? Abaixo segue o código para leitura de visualização do banco de dados.

```
url <- "https://raw.githack.com/fulgenciomath/stackOverflow/master/futdata.csv"
library(data.table)
data <- fread(url,encoding = "Latin-1")
```

Answer (score 5):

Basta a função sub/gsub do `base`:

```
data$Rodada <- gsub("ª", "", data$Rodada)
```

Ou, usando a sintaxe do *data.table* :

```
data[, Rodada := gsub("ª", "", Rodada)]
```

Pode também remover o "RODADA" e converter para numérico. Só usar `as.integer(sub("ª RODADA$", "", Rodada))`

Answer (score 4):

Você pode utilizar o pacote stringr e chamar a função str_replace_all

```
url <- "https://raw.githack.com/fulgenciomath/stackOverflow/master/futdata.csv"
library(data.table)
data <- fread(url,encoding = "Latin-1")   

library(stringr)

data$Rodada <- str_replace_all(data$Rodada, "ª", "")
```

Saída:

```
 [1] "1 RODADA" "1 RODADA" "1 RODADA" "1 RODADA" "1 RODADA" "1 RODADA"
 [7] "1 RODADA" "1 RODADA" "1 RODADA" "2 RODADA"
```